# How to calculate the height of a TCategoryButtons at run-time?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 VCL Application in Windows 10, how can I calculate the height of a `TCategoryButtons` object at run-time, i.e. the sum of all its button heights and its Category items, as this height could vary depending on its font size?

Measuring the pixel heights at run-time, I have noticed that all buttons have the same height and that the buttons have a different height as the Category items.

Also, note that the buttons do not have a published Height property in the Object Inspector.

But shouldn't it be possible to calculate the sum of all its button heights and its Category items with some low-level methods?

Comment: And of course, the height also depends on the `ButtonOptions`: for instance, you can have the category caption next to the buttons or above them; you can have one button per row or multiple buttons per row (with automatic wrapping!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a control entirely implemented in Pascal, in Vcl.CategoryButtons.pas.

Therefore, you can see exactly how it is implemented. For instance, in `TCategoryButtons.Paint` you see its complete drawing code. Similarly, you can investigate the hit testing done in `MouseMove` (or `MouseDown` or `MouseUp`).

Consequently, if nothing else, you can create your own modified version of `TCategoryButtons` using this code. Your version can save the total height when it has been determined (for instance, certainly after painting).

However, after a quick look, it seems like `TButtonCategory.Bounds` might be interesting. If you are lucky, this returns the on-screen rect of a category. The `Bottom` of the last category's rect should be the (effectively used) height of the entire control.

It seems to work for me:

[image: Screen recording of a TCategoryButtons control being used (categories colapsed and expanded, buttons moved between categories). As the controls effectively used height varies, a red bar's height is updated accordingly.]

Here I draw a red bar of the same height as the control.

```pascal
procedure TForm5.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var y := CategoryButtons1.Categories[
    CategoryButtons1.Categories.Count - 1
  ].Bounds.Bottom;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, ClientWidth, y))
end;
```

Comment: This is an ingenious idea and it works well! However, when setting the height of the CategoryButtons with this method in the Form's `OnPaint` event, I have to add a **1 pixel offset** to avoid scrollbars in the CategoryButtons control: `CategoryButtons1.Height := CategoryButtons1.Categories[CategoryButtons1.Categories.Count - 1].Bounds.Bottom + 1;` BTW, using this method I could implement an `Autosize` property of a control derived from `TCategoryButtons`.

Comment: It turns out that the offset depends from `BorderWidth`. (In my practical case I use `BorderStyle = bsNone` and `BorderWidth = 0`). So when using a border width > 0 then the formula should be: `CategoryButtons1.Height := CategoryButtons1.Categories[CategoryButtons1.Categories.Count - 1].Bounds.Bottom + 1 + CategoryButtons1.BorderWidth`

Comment: BTW, looking at all your ingenious solutions, IMO you should be a top developer at Embarcadero!

Comment: @user1580348: Correct. The coordinates used when painting the control's contents are its client area coordinates, which exclude the border (same kind of difference if you compare a form's `Height` and `ClientHeight`, say). I realised that I should have removed the border after I posted the A (or added the border width in the formula, as you do), but was too lazy to redo the screen recording (maybe I'm getting old). And thanks for the compliments!